# Do file operations in NodeJS make use of OS async (polling?) or does it block the event loop?

Tags: node.js

Do file operations in NodeJS make use of OS async (polling?) or does it block the event loop?
I want to create a webapp that requires a lot of uploading and I'm worried this may cause delays.

Comment: [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html) is pretty clear in that it can do both; is there anything in particular you find missing?

Comment: Async doesn't mean that it doesn't block the event loop though.

Comment: If I have many users uploading files, is this going to block the event loop and block the app. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling is not used.

> does it block the event loop?

It will if you use the sync versions. For example, using `readFileSync` will block other JS from running until the file is read and comes back. This could well be a problem if multiple parts of the script call such a method at different times.

But if you use the asynchronous versions (for example, `readFile`) which either accept a callback or return a Promise, they will not block other JS from running while the file operation is going on.

When in doubt, use one of the asynchronous versions - I'd only use the sync versions for smaller apps with segments of code that will only run once, such as for the initial reading of a config file, for which preventing other JS from running during that one-time delay isn't an issue.